# Gitlab Proxy issue with Private Maven repository in Android Gradle project

Tags: android, maven, gradle, proxy, gitlab

I have an Android project that uses Gitlab for CI/CD. Gitlab is behind a proxy and it is not easily accessible, but dependencies from other repositories work as expected. For example from:

```
 google()
 mavenCentral()
 maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

Now I also have a private custom maven that uses authentication. I've setup everything and locally, where the machine is not behind a proxy, it works ok:

```
    maven {
        name 'myCustomRepositoryTestDebug'
        credentials {
            username project.findProperty('myMavenRepoUser') ?: System.getenv("CI_MY_MAVEN_REPO_USER")
            password project.findProperty('mnyMavenRepoPassword') ?: System.getenv("CI_MY_MAVEN_REPO_PASSWORD")
        }
        url 'https://myapi.something.me/repo/test-debug'
    }
    maven {
        name 'myCustomRepositoryTestRelease'
        credentials {
            username project.findProperty('myMavenRepoUser') ?: System.getenv("CI_MY_MAVEN_REPO_USER")
            password project.findProperty('myMavenRepoPassword') ?: System.getenv("CI_MY_MAVEN_REPO_PASSWORD")
        }
        url 'https://myapi.custom.me/repo/test-release'
    }
```

on Gitlab job I'm getting:

```
Could not resolve com.mylibrary:MyLibrary-release:5.0.0.
     > Could not get resource 'https:/myapi.custom.me/repo/test-release/com/mylibrary/MyLibrary-release/5.0.0/MyLibrary-release-5.0.0.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://myapi.custom.me/repo/test-release/com/mylibrary/MyLibrary-release/5.0.0/MyLibrary-release-5.0.0.pom'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable
```

Sometimes I get code 500. Not sure why it is not always the same.

Locally everything works perfectly.
What am I missing on Gitlab?

PS: I don't have direct access to the runner or to the machine where Gitlab is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have proxy problem in github, you can wirte "git config --global http.proxy 172.25.1.2:3129" in gitbash.
Or you can add proxy setting in android studio.

Comment: Locally it works ok, but Gitlab instance is behind a proxy and this is the reason why this is not working, although other maven repositories are working ok. The issue is only for the private one that I have. 
Can I do that in my yaml file ? To run that command before running the gradle task ?

Comment: you can try by this code

Comment: image: docker:20.10.16

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

services:
  - docker:20.10.16-dind

build:
  image: docker:20.10.16
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_USER -p $CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_PASSWORD $CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_SERVER
  script:
    -  docker build -t test .

Comment: and if you have problem connect me. Skype id : Hui Jin
Skype name : live:.cid.d49a56ccc8f00388

Comment: proxy works for anything else, except for the gradlew command when trying to get the artifact from the private repository

Comment: I'm using `eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy` image for my pipeline